# How to split array list into multiple rows and columns in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, arraylist

I am reading this XML file using scala and I had to define custom schema's for each table attribute as they are different.

```
<CATALOG>
    <TABLE at_name="Furniture">
        <ROWDATA>
            <ROW typeid="0" caseid="0" key="1" code="0"/>
            <ROW typeid="1" caseid="0" key="1" code="0"/>
            <ROW typeid="1" caseid="1" key="1" code="0"/>
        </ROWDATA>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE at_name="Cutlery">
        <ROWDATA>
            <ROW cutleryTypeid="0" color="Blue" code="0"/>
            <ROW cutleryTypeid="0" color="Blue" code="0"/>
        </ROWDATA>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE at_name="Apparel">
        <ROWDATA>
            <ROW ApparelTypeid="1" color="Blue" barcode="0111"/>
            <ROW ApparelTypeid="0" color="Blue" barcode"1122"/>
        </ROWDATA>
    </TABLE>
<CATALOG>
```

I now have the following array list created like this(for attribute furniture):

```
 val gl = DF.select("ROWDATA").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
    for(element<-gl)
    {
      println(element)
    }
```

When I print the elements I get this:

```
[WrappedArray([0,0,1,0], [1,0,1,0], [1,1,1,0])]
```

I want this transformed into two outputs.
Output 1:

```
id   elements
1    [0,0,1,0]
2    [1,0,1,0]
3    [1,0,1,0]
```

Then I want convert it like this:
Output 2:

```
id   col1  col2  col3   col4
1    0     0     1       0
2    1     0     1       0
3    1     0     1       0
```

Any help on this please?

Comment: show the raw data that is better to understand.

Comment: @Lamanus please see edit